# Identify this large (swamp) fly?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Can anyone identify this large fly?

I encountered it in Okefenokee Swamp (Georgia, U.S.A.) on May 1, 2015. 
Weather: 53-78°F (avg. 66°F), avg humidity = 60, dew point = 47°F.

The fly was about the size of an adult thumb (more accurately approx. 5cm long and 2cm wide) -- this fly was HUGE! It was fairly docile and allowed me to take a good close-up or 2.

[image: Large Swamp Fly]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Tabanus nigrovittatus* as my initial guess. "Greenhead horse fly."

[image]

[Source](http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/page/6270326#page/328/mode/1up)

This is probably the biggest give-away for the genus Tabanus (namely the features of the veins at the wing tip, denoted R4 and R5, *versus* other Diptera orders), still searching out a good identification key to solidify the ID. Furthermore, also known as the salt marsh greenhead, a swamp is a good candidate to find these [(1)](http://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/62737-Tabanus-nigrovittatus).

So what's particular is entomologists have gone through and collected many specimens, and data about their wing venation, and based on the [Comstock-Needham system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comstock%E2%80%93Needham_system), you can pin presence/absence of major veins, and branching of said veins to specific types on insects. In this case, R refers to the Radius or 3rd longitudinal vein, and the number refers part of the branching that reaches the margin of the wing. Pg 156 [here](http://ag.udel.edu/delpha/1949.pdf) helps us ID Tabanus vs other orders.

Problematic with identifying these spp. is you need to get a good look at the sternites on the under side as well, if you look at how they ID *Tabanus sudeticus* [here](http://influentialpoints.com/Gallery/Tabanus_sudeticus_Dark_giant_horsefly.htm), but the photos tend to match nicely with those of *T. nigrovittatus* you can widely find.

Comment: You should add a bit on why you think this a good fit (traits etc), but my first impression was also *Tabanus sp*. As the moment, this is more of a comment than a full answer. FYI it was caught by the low-quality review queue "*because of its length and content*".

Comment: Believe it or not it's really hard to find a good identification key for Tabanus species!

Comment: @Kendall could you comment what about the R4 & R5 wing features (i.e., what is unique about these features as compared to other genera's wings) that demonstrate that this is a *Tabanus* species?

Comment: @theforestecologist I've done so in an edit to my post, let me know how I can better clarify this!

Comment: @Kendall Great!! The Comstock-Needham system is very fascinating (and fairly easy to learn)! I don't get the nomenclature for the R2+3 vein though... Also, the vein nomenclature in the image you reference on p156 of the Hamilton paper does not match the nomenclature of the image you've presented here. Could you also provide the link to the image you included and perhaps a comment on the discrepancy. Finally, could you present a citation or key indicating the importance of sternites (and other characteristics). Thanks!!

Comment: @theforestecologist Most of the nomenclature discrepancy I suspect is  from the fact the article by Hamilton is trying to do something different. I can't quote you on when the distinction was made, but R2+3 means that the vein R2 and the vein R3 coalesce through their extent in a single vein. Here's your image source http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/page/6270326#page/328/mode/1up .. for more on the nomenclature, [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2452973?seq=4#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: It's  my thought while researching this that Tabanus is rather poorly defined!

Comment: @Kendall: your answer and subsequent comments have been very helpful (and interesting!).  However after having examined multiple photos of *T. nigrovittatus* and both photos /memory of the fly I saw, I Just am not convinced that the species is accurate. The wing veins do seem to support *Tabanus*. I will leave the question open (no accepted answer) to see if someone can provide additional expertise

Comment: @theforestecologist Unfortunately im not a specialist (just good at getting what I need out of the literature quickly). I did try quite hard to find an identification/dichotomous key, and outside of wing venation, the documentation is really scarce and photos simply don't help on average. Another good candidate: *T. bovinus*. The problem is distribution; the well-studied Tabanus spp. are often endemic to Europe/associated areas. "Salt-marsh greenhead" as *T. nigrovittatus* is often called fits the distribution, but you could viably contact an actual entomologist at a uni. department!

Comment: FYI (since this is the most relevant place I can think to place this cool find): here is a super cool website to look graphically at fly anatomical parts!! ["Tha Anatomical Atlas of Flies"](http://www.ento.csiro.au/biology/fly/flyGlossary.html)